# MDCars overlaps MDTextfield

Tags: kivy, kivymd

i am currently trying to build a app but after adding the ScreenManager i came across a problem. My MDCard is overlapping my MDTextField... Without a MDCard i am able to use my TextField but i don't want to enter any fixed positions due to the missplacement that happens on my phone. Is there a way to put the MDCard in the background?

login.kv

```
MDCard:
    #### Card config
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 600, 900
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    elevation: 10
    padding: 25
    spacing: 25
    orientation: 'vertical'

    #### Label - Welcome
    MDLabel:
        id: welcome_label
        text: "WELCOME"
        font_size: 100
        halign: 'center'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        padding_y: 800

    #### Textfield - IP-Address
    MDTextField:
        id: ip_address
        #text: "test"
        hint_text: "IP-Address"
        icon_right: "lan-connect"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 400
        font_size: 40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = """
MDCard:
    padding: 25
    spacing: 25
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDLabel:
        text: "WELCOME"
        halign: 'center'
        adaptive_height: True

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "IP-Address"
        icon_right: "lan-connect"
"""


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

And what you are doing seems absurd.